# Перевод SQL запроса из Firebird в PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, firebird

Доброго времени суток,
есть SQL запрос из Firebird и его желательно перевести в PostgreSQL, [тут код](http://pastebin.com/z03gGjy2), который я пытаюсь перевести, снизу я написал то, что я сам смог перевести.

Мои познания в базах данных слабы, да и собственно никогда с ними не работал, а тут внезапно решили проект перевести на другую СУБД и вот самый "вкусный кусок" работы мне достался.